# Facing 500 series Error while running Jmeter Selenium script in Azure pipeline

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, exception, azure-devops, remote-webdriver

while executing the Jmeter selenium scripts in azure pipeline ,I repeatedly seeing the error 500 error saying that "No Such Session Found"

But while running the same script in our Virtual Machine script is working fine for large no.of iterations.

kindly help me in this issuse. I attached the Error what we are facing below .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJlec.png

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Selenium for performance testing is [not recommended by Selenium developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.
2. Using Selenium for performance testing is [not recommended by WebDriver Sampler developers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

If you **really** need to conduct browser-based performance testing make sure to install:

1. The browser (i.e. [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) or [Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-projects/))
2. The relevant version of WebDriver (i.e. [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) or [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/))
3. Make sure to configure the WebDriver to run in [headless mode](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/)
4. Follow webdriver and operating system documentation, i.e. if you're [running Chromedriver under super user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828470/how-to-run-selenium-chromedriver-as-root-not-working-even-with-no-sandbox) you need to pass `--no-sandbox` command-line argument

For further assistance please share request and response details from [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, your JMeter configuration and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

However it's better to use JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, given you [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) there should be no difference at all from the system under test perspective, resource footprint will be much lower and you will be able to collect more comprehensive test results and metrics.

Comment: we want to know how much time the UI gonna take to load during our load test is the purpose so that ,we follow 90 % percent load in HTTP samples and only 10% load in UI .
to run that JMETER selenium scripts in azure pipeline we facing the above issues like NO Such session, but while running same in anyone of Virtual machine what we had , it working good.
@Dmitri T Kindly help me in this issues

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJlec.png   - error from jmeter view results tree.

jmeter version in pipeline - 5.5

I am already use sandbox command in my code and headless mode only in linux OS which is available in Azure pipeline